# Ultima Data e Hora ao fazer o Login

Tags: php, data

Eu coloquei essa linha no código **php**:

```
$lastlogdate=time();
```

Para pegar a data e a hora ao fazer o login, mais quando vou ver fica assim:

```
1397562733
```

Eu queria que fica-se assim:

```
17/04/14
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa formatar sua data, pois o `time()` traz as data em milissegundos desde **01/01/1990**. Tente isso:

```
$lastlogdate=date('d/M/Y', time());
```

Fonte: [epochconverter](http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/functions-php.php#epoch2date)

Comment: Valeu Cara, Me Ajudou.